# How to decrease row space in HTML table that been warped by String builder

Tags: html, css, asp.net

How to decrease row space in HTML table that been warped by String builder.

[image]

```
    sbRetVal.Append(" <table width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='1'><tr><td style='vertical-align:top;width:13px' rowspan='4'><img height='84' width='84' src='" + Globals.gRootRelativeSecureURL("/Images/Layout/User-blue-icon.png") + "'/></td><td>Name: " + drOfficer("UserName") + " </td></tr><tr><td >Location: " + drOfficer("LocationName") + " </td></tr> <tr><td >Cell: " + " 1-888-423-210" + " </td></tr><tr><td>Title: " + "Regional" + " </td></tr></table>")
```

Comment: I have space between the rows

Comment: Webforms or MVC? Do you have to use a string builder? Could you not have your layout already on the webfroms page or MVC view with place holders for the dynimic info? Then all you have to do is update the placeholders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something else has to be affecting the   or  tags, wondering what other stylesheets are called that influence....inspect your rendered source and over ride the problem after you find the root of the padding...or more details please

Comment: This would be better served as a comment. This is not an answer. Then again it's not much of a question.